# Output and EventEmtiter not sending any data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, output, eventemitter

I want to send data from my child component to my parent component using the Output() and EventEmitter methods. However, it appears as though nothing is being sent through, despite the function the emitter is in being hit in the child component?

My child component:

```js
@Output() urlStringEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.startUpload();
  }

startUpload() {
    // Unrelated Code Above ^^^^
    // Assign URL's to Array
    this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      last(),
      switchMap(() => ref.getDownloadURL())
    ).subscribe(url => {
      this.urlStringEvent.emit(url);
    })
  }
```

In the above startUpload() method, the 'url' response is sent through, however nothing seems to happen with 'this.urlStringEvent.emit(url);'

In my parent component (component.html):

```html
<app-upload-task-training (showEvent)="receiveUrlString($event)"></app-upload-task-training>
```

component.ts:

```
receiveUrlString($event: any) {
    console.log($event);
  }
```

Nothing is logged in the $event as seen above, why could this be?

Comment: Your parent component expects `showEvent` to fire, not `urlStringEvent `. Could you change that and give us update?

Comment: This was the issue. Apologies on my end, this was a silly oversight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not properly name the **event** in your `html`. Change `html` code like this:

```
<app-upload-task-training (urlStringEvent)="receiveUrlString($event)"></app-upload-task-training>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are emitting `urlStringEvent` but in `html` you using `showEvent`, It will not work either you can change your html like this

```
<app-upload-task-training (urlStringEvent)="receiveUrlString($event)"></app-upload-task-training>
```

**OR**

Change this

```
@Output() urlStringEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

to this

```
@Output('showEvent') urlStringEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
```